# React HandleDelete TypeError undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-rails

I have React component called Websites to handle state

```
class Websites extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleWebsiteDelete = this.handleWebsiteDelete.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      websites: this.props.websites
    }
  }

  handleWebsiteDelete(id) {
    console.log("delete")
    // How to Run This Function?
    // ...further code to delete id from state.websites
  }

  render () {
    return(
      <div className="row">
        {
          this.state.websites.map(function(website, index) {
            return (
              <WebsiteItem key={website.id} {...website} onDelete={this.handleWebsiteDelete}/>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then I have React component called WebsiteItem with a function handleDelete an object:

```
class WebsiteItem extends React.Component {

  handleDelete(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      method: "DELETE",
      url: "/websites/" + this.props.id 
    })
      .done(function(){
        this.props.onDelete(this.props.id);
      }.bind(this))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        {this.props.name}
        <a href="#" onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}>Delete</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My goal is to delete a website from a server using ajax inside WebsiteItem component (successfully done) and run a function `onDelete` inside Websites component to update the state `this.state.websites`.

I can't manage to run the function with an error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onDelete is not a function` - I tried to play with bind(this) but not sure if I complete understand it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right.

You have to `bind` the callback function you are passing to `this.state.websites.map()` to your component instance.

In order to do it, you have to pass the context as the second argument to `.map()`

```
{
    this.state.websites.map(function(website, index) {
        return (
          <WebsiteItem key={website.id} {...website} onDelete={this.handleWebsiteDelete}/>
        )
    },this)
}
```

Or use arrow functions

```
{
    this.state.websites.map((website, index) => {
        return (
          <WebsiteItem key={website.id} {...website} onDelete={this.handleWebsiteDelete}/>
        )
    })
}
```